# Quarkus JPA Hibernate Statistics show multiple connections being used under the same transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus

I've a project which use quarkus and hibernate to access a postgresql database. Doing some testing I've found that the hibernate statistics for each request are reporting that more than one connection is being used per request. I though that all queries executed under the hood of the same transaction will use the same phisical connection, but I'm not sure if this is happening rigth now.

I've made an example available [here](https://github.com/javiertoja/playground/tree/master/quarkus/hibernate-orm-quickstart), Where if you download and execute the test will se the same behaviour. The test executes and endpoint where the same query is executed four times whithin a transaction

Based on this piece of code:

```
2020-08-21 16:28:13,079 INFO  [org.hib.eng.int.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] (executor-thread-1) Session Metrics {
    5371760 nanoseconds spent acquiring 4 JDBC connections;
    61585 nanoseconds spent releasing 4 JDBC connections;
    18094275 nanoseconds spent preparing 4 JDBC statements;
    19146452 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Does anyone knows if the JDBC connections refer to phisical connections to the database or just that the entity manager have requested four times connection to the connection pool?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 times request from connection pool. Each query you do is doable in one statement each thus why you have same use of queries as connections.